# -interpreter-exec console of lldb command

Tags: lldb

what does --interpreter-exec console "lldb command" mean ? 
is it equivalent to lldb-mi command of particular lldb command? 
for example to break in lldb we use "b main", but in lldb-mi we use "-break-insert main". 
I am guessing --interpreter-exec console "b main" is equivalent to "-break-insert main" in lldb-mi. Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent but not exactly identical.  `b <STRING>` actually does a moderately complicated job of parsing `<STRING>` to try to replicate (and extend) the gdb breakpoint syntax.  The `--break-insert` MI command does a less complicated job that just supports a smaller subset of the gdb breakpoint syntax.  For strings like "main" - a function name, "0x12345" - and address, or "foo.c:12" - file and line, the two are functionally equivalent, however.